# Combine or construct value from multiple array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have many arrays like these, the amounts are dynamic, can be 3, 10, 35 and so on...

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
...
...
```

Then I want to create a combination value out of them like these:

```
[
111, // combine from: first arr idx 0, second arr idx 0, third arr idx 0
112, // idx 0, idx 0, idx 1
113,
114
]

[
121, // idx 0, idx 1, idx 0
122,
123,
124 // idx 0, idx 1, idx 3
]

[131, 132, 133, 134]

[
211,  // idx 1, idx 0, idx 0
212,
213,
214
]

[221, 222, 223, 224]
...
...
```

If the amounts of source arrays are static, lets say always 3, it can be easily to accomplish by using nested `for` loop.

But I am struggling to solve this because they are dynamic, sometimes just 2 arrays and other time can be 15 arrays.

> Note that the integer values are just examples, I should've used string.

Comment: I have reopened the question. But, the approach is similar: [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989)

Comment: @adiga thanks, yeah the question right there is exactly similar to mine

Comment: It's not exactly the same because you have one more level of grouping.